# make error says separator not found

Tags: makefile

This is the code snippet where, on the first like,  make says separator not found

```
.if !empty(_MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX)

.error MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX can only be set in environment, not as a global\

        (in make.conf(5)) or command-line variable.

.endif
```

All lines are left aligned. If I place a tab \t before the .if, which is a suggested correction for such errors, I get the following message

**commands commence before first target.  Stop.**

What might be the bug? Should I change anything else in the make file?
Thank You!

Comment: What is your `make` version? Does it have `if`? Most of what I'm aware of only have `ifeq`, `ifneq` and `ifdef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax above looks like it is for BSD make.  The error message suggests you're using GNU make; this syntax will not work with GNU make and you cannot use that makefile with GNU make.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!It is a makefile for BSD after-all. Do you know if there is there any BSD make available to be run on a Linux machine?

Comment: Well, FreeBSD tools are free software as well so you can always get the source and build it.  However sometimes those tools are written specifically for that environment and have special requirements that make them not so portable.  I have no idea if BSD make is one of them.  If you have a Debian-based system (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) you can try installing the `freebsd-buildutils` package which seems to have some BSD tools like BSD `make`.  There may be something similar on Red Hat-based systems, not sure.